# javascript how to clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/89qZM/1/

```
...
 searchAndRepairRules: function(externalStyleSheetContents) {
                var contents = [];
                    alert(externalStyleSheetContents); //externalStyleSheetContents
                    contents = externalStyleSheetContents;
                    contents[0] = 0;
                    alert(externalStyleSheetContents); //0
        },
...
```

Why when I affect contents it also affects externalStyleSheetContents and how can I avoid it? Help please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because objects are always passed by reference.

To clone an array, use `newarr = oldarr.slice(0);`